# Program is returning two different types of output

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-arrays

Beginner programmer here. The code below runs fine; however, the program may output two different types of values. At some points, the program will output the correct values. Other times (the majority of the time), it will output an incorrect and ridiculous value. For example, the correct value for hiAvg should be ~89. However, at random times, it will return 6,638,000 instead.

All of the other arrays shown below containing integers work perfectly fine except for the hiTemp array. I've spent quite a few hours trying to figure out why this is happening, and I can't come up with any solutions.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <fstream>    
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    //C++ struct to contain 6 values for each city 
    struct dynArr{

    //Contain pointers for to set as dynamic arrays
    string *cityName;
    int *hiTemp;
    int *loTemp;
    string *fcastStr;
    int *fhiTemp;
    int *floTemp;   

    int size;
    };

    //Function to read in the file
    void openFile ( dynArr & arr1 ){

       arr1.size = 10;

       //Allocating the dynamic arrays  
       arr1.cityName = new string[arr1.size];
       arr1.hiTemp = new int[arr1.size];
       arr1.loTemp = new int[arr1.size];
       arr1.fcastStr = new string[arr1.size];
       arr1.fhiTemp = new int[arr1.size];
       arr1.floTemp = new int[arr1.size];

       string city;
       int hi, lo;
       string fcast;
       int fhi, flo;

       //Prompt user for a file input
       ifstream is; 
       cout << "Enter name of file: ";
       char fname2[80];
       cin >> fname2;

       is.open (fname2, ios::in);

       int i = 0;
       is >> city;
       while ( ! is.eof() ){
            is  >>  hi >> lo >> fcast >> fhi >> flo;

            //Increase size of dynamic arrays if necessary
            if ( i >= arr1.size){

                string *tempStr1;
                tempStr1 = new string[arr1.size*2];
                string *tempStr2;
                tempStr2 = new string[arr1.size*2];

                int *tempInt1;
                tempInt1 = new int[arr1.size*2];
                int *tempInt2;
                tempInt2 = new int[arr1.size*2];
                int *tempInt3;
                tempInt3 = new int[arr1.size*2];
                int *tempInt4;
                tempInt4 = new int[arr1.size*2];

                for (int a = 0; a < arr1.size; a++){
                    tempStr1[a] = arr1.cityName[a];
                    tempStr2[a] = arr1.fcastStr[a];

                    tempInt1[a] = arr1.hiTemp[a];
                    tempInt2[a] = arr1.loTemp[a];
                    tempInt3[a] = arr1.fhiTemp[a];
                    tempInt4[a] = arr1.floTemp[a];
                }


                delete[] arr1.cityName;
                delete[] arr1.fcastStr;
                delete[] arr1.hiTemp;
                delete[] arr1.loTemp;
                delete[] arr1.fhiTemp;
                delete[] arr1.floTemp;

                arr1.cityName = tempStr1;
                arr1.fcastStr = tempStr2;
                arr1.hiTemp = tempInt1;
                arr1.loTemp = tempInt2;
                arr1.fhiTemp = tempInt3;
                arr1.floTemp = tempInt4;

                arr1.size = arr1.size*2;
            }

            //Store the read in values into the dynamic arrays
            arr1.cityName[i] = city;
            arr1.hiTemp[i] = hi;
            arr1.loTemp[i] = lo;
            arr1.fcastStr[i] = fcast;
            arr1.fhiTemp[i] = fhi;
            arr1.floTemp[i] = flo;

            i++;
            is >> city; 
            }
    }

    //Function to calculate average of high and low temperatures
    void func1 (dynArr & arr1){

       int count = 0;
       for (int a = 0; a < 400; a++){
           if ( arr1.cityName[a] != "" ){
                count = count + 1;
           }
       }

       float hiSum = 0;
       float loSum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            hiSum = hiSum + arr1.hiTemp[i];
            loSum = loSum + arr1.loTemp[i];
           }        

       float hiAvg = hiSum/count;
       float loAvg = loSum/count;

       cout << "The average high temperature for all of the cities: " << hiAvg << endl;
       cout << "The average low temperature for all of the cities: " << loAvg << endl;
    }

    int main() {
       dynArr arr1;
       openFile(arr1);
       func1(arr1);

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop using `new[]` and `delete[]` and instead use `std::vector`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to use vectors quite yet. Though, I will definitely try soon. But I can't get over the curiosity as to why the code above is acting that way.

Comment: Fyi, this: `while ( ! is.eof() )` is wrong. [Read here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Yep, I know. Though, my instructor taught us to use and wants us to use that line of while loop.

Comment: @dendritic Your instructor needs instructing.

Comment: Lol, he is pretty old though. So that line of while loop may be the root of my issue with this code?

Comment: Well, it doesn't help, but the biggest problem I see is your average calculation. `for (int a = 0; a < 400; a++){` Um. you're using `a` to index an array that, based on your input, stands no chance of being 400 elements long, yet there is nothing preventing you from dereferencing non-existent nodes . that loop has disaster written all over it. A dynamic array is pointless without knowing its *real magnitude*. And your input loop seems to be missing quite a bit as well.

Comment: Hm.. I think I'm starting to see the problem.

Comment: The main problem is that you are confusing `size` with `capacity`.  Nowhere in your code do you know the actual number of entries.  Yes, you have a `size` member, but look closely -- it doesn't give you the real size.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I found the problem. It's definitely that for loop I wrote with 400 elements long. But then what other ways can I do to get a value of "count" that will show how many items there are in a list?

Comment: @dendritic Like I said, the main reason for the problem is that you forgot the most basic thing -- a count of the number of items actually read in.  Instead, you're resorting to a loop to figure out how many items. That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is making a for loop after the "i++" increment of: for (int a = 0; a < i; a++). In that case, the value of "a" should be the count of the number of items. But how would I return that value from that openFile function?

Comment: @dendritic Why do you need a loop at all to get the count?  Just add a member variable to your `dynArr` class, start it out at 0, and increment it for each record you read in.  Then you use that member to get the count.  There is no need for a loop, and quite frankly, a dynamic array class is absolutely worthless if it didn't know the number of items it has.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long and frustrating day for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fyi, this is how one might do this with a vector. I think you'll see it considerably less contorted. Best of luck: [See it live](http://ideone.com/rAV0Fv).

Comment: You get it wrong, instead of structure of multiple cityNames, hiTemps etc, you should have structure with one cityName, hiTemp, loTemp and so on, and then array (vector) of that structures. You are going wrong way.

Comment: Thank you all for your invaluable feedbacks.

Comment: @WhozCraig your `friend` is redundant as your struct only has public members

Comment: @MattMcNabb some habits are hard to kick, aren't they?